# C# skip the value if it is null and move on to next value json property Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: c#, json, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a program that I want to get the rev no. and the System.ChangedDate from JSON body.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qfEV.png) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmorV.png). Both pictures are taken from Microsoft docs as examples.
[Microsoft Docs (Updates - List)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

I can get the rev no. and value for System.ChangedDate using REST API.

The problem that I am running into is when there is no value for System.ChangedDate([Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1yYf.png)), it will stop at getting the rev no. and can't proceed to the next value for rev no and the date.

Result that I get currently:

[Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP4h4.png). It stops at rev: 4 (rev :4 id:5 don't have value for system.changeddate) and can't proceed to rev: 5.

What I have tried:

```
        public WorkItemUpdate GetUpdates(int Id)
     {            
        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync($"_apis/wit/workItems/{Id}/updates?&api-version=6.0").Result;
        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkItemUpdate>(resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

```
            var updateid = RestAPI.GetUpdates(id);
            Console.WriteLine("Count: " + updateid.count);

            foreach (var m in updateid.value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("id: " + m.id);
                Console.WriteLine("rev: " + m.rev);

                if (m.fields.SystemChangedDate.newValue != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ChangedDate: " + m.fields.SystemChangedDate.newValue);
                }

            }
```

Any suggestion on this?

**EDIT:**

Screenshot with revision without System.ChangedDate: [Picture 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN7km.png)

We can see from Picture 5 when there is no System.ChangedDate value, it can't continue to the next item which is id:6 rev:5, it just stops at id:5 rev:4 without giving any error. The Json body looks like Picture 1 when there is no field for System.ChangedDate. I want it to skip and just proceed to the next item. I try with null/string.IsNullOrEmpty but it can't work.

System.ChangedDate will have a new value every time the workitem has update. Maybe on the System.State/System.Reason etc....

Comment: I think you have to add Picture 3 to get the more clear question.

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander Thanks for reply. Would like to ask which part is not clear enough  in this question so I can add?

Comment: A screenshot with revision without System.ChangedDate will be useful here. But that`s strange because  the System.ChangedDate has to be updated each time.

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander Hi Sir, the question is edited. Hope you can have a look.

Comment: `if (m.fields.SystemChangedDate.newValue != null)` throws a NullReferenceException, because m.fields is an optional attribute (i.e. is null for some cases). Your null-checking here only applies to the _newValue_ attribute ignoring the nested object structure. You should check for each nested object, whether it is null. For example `if (m.fields?.SystemChangedDate?.newValue != null)` would make use of [null-conditionals operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Comment: @SME_Dev Thank you so much. It works with the null-conditionals operator.